# Multiple conditions in a single Case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have the SQL update statement like:

```
UPDATE OPTY
SET OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST =
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(OPTY_LIST.LB_ENTITY_LIST, 1, 1) = ',' 
        THEN REPLACE(OPTY_LIST.LB_ENTITY_LIST, 
            SUBSTRING(OPTY_LIST.LB_ENTITY_LIST, 1, 1), '')
    ELSE OPTY_LIST.LB_ENTITY_LIST
    END
FROM SALES_DTM_PBI.dbo.TD_OPPORTUNITY OPTY
LEFT JOIN #TMP_LB_ENTITY_LISTPerOptyConcatenated OPTY_LIST ON
OPTY.ID_TECH_OPTY = OPTY_LIST.ID_TECH_OPTY

UPDATE OPTY
SET OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST =
    CASE WHEN OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST LIKE '%&amp;amp;%' 
        THEN REPLACE(OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;')
    ELSE OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST
    END
FROM SALES_DTM_PBI.dbo.TD_OPPORTUNITY OPTY

UPDATE OPTY
SET OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST = CASE
    WHEN OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST LIKE '%,,%' 
        THEN REPLACE(OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST, ',,', ',')
    ELSE OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST
    END
FROM SALES_DTM_PBI.dbo.TD_OPPORTUNITY OPTY
```

But I want to have a single update statement. The data that I am getting in `#TMP_LB_ENTITY_LISTPerOptyConcatenated` for the column `LB_ENTITY_LIST` is `MU DE LS &amp;amp; EUC,,` but the data I want in `TD_OPPORTUNITY` is `MU DE LS &amp; EUC,`. As it is having multiple conditions of `&amp;amp;` and `,,` so I wrote two update statements as if I will give 1 case statement and multiple when in that then if some `LB_ENTITY_LIST` is having two things `&amp;amp;` and `,,` like the one which I showed then it will take the case of only first when statement and then it will go to end.

So is there any way in which I can do by using single case. So that I don't have to use a multiple update statements.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a single, atomic value - **NOT** a statement!

Comment: @marc_s yaa that I know but I am asking that if a data is having multiple condition of a case statement then what to do to make that data fulfill all the cases. If I make a case when SUBSTRING(LB_ENTITY_LIST,1,1) =',' then REPLACE(LB_ENTITY_LIST,SUBSTRING(LB_ENTITY_LIST,1,1),'')
when LB_ENTITY_LIST like '%&amp;amp;%' then REPLACE(LB_ENTITY_LIST,'&amp;amp;','&amp;')
when  LB_ENTITY_LIST like '%,,' then REPLACE(LB_ENTITY_LIST,',,',',')
else LB_ENTITY_LIST
Now if the data follow both the cases first one as well as second one then it will only satisfy first condition and will move to end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the simplest answer for you is to use replace and trim instead of case:

here is a little example:

```
declare @aaa as nvarchar(50)
set @aaa = N',MU DE LS &amp;amp; EUC,,'

select @aaa
select REPLACE(@aaa, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;')
select REPLACE(REPLACE(@aaa, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;'), ',,', ',')
--First trim is for removing the first comma, keep notice that i added a space at the end to keep the last comma, then i trimmed again the spaces
SELECT TRIM(TRIM(',' from (REPLACE(REPLACE(@aaa, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;'), ',,', ',') + ' ')))
```

In your case you just need to do this:

```
UPDATE OPTY
SET OPTY.LB_ENTITY_LIST = TRIM(TRIM(',' from (REPLACE(REPLACE(OPTY_LIST.LB_ENTITY_LIST, '&amp;amp;', '&amp;'), ',,', ',') + ' ')))
FROM SALES_DTM_PBI.dbo.TD_OPPORTUNITY OPTY
LEFT JOIN #TMP_LB_ENTITY_LISTPerOptyConcatenated OPTY_LIST ON OPTY.ID_TECH_OPTY = OPTY_LIST.ID_TECH_OPTY
```